# PHP Cookie is not set/working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I tried a lot but did not find what is the mistake. kindly tell me in detail/example how this will work for me. I am trying to set cookie for a login form. here are basic steps that I have implements.

1) HTML and CSS code for creating login form.
2) Implement jQuery to check that login form should be filled correctly. And after checking I used $.post method from jQuery to post the form to php file, that will handle the login.
3) PHP file that will connect to database. If username and password are correct then this PHP should create a cookie <-- (This will not working).
4) After creating cookie, I send the username back to jQuery file $.post function (data).
5) If data is not equal to error then It will go to members.php. If data == error than It says that username / password is wrong.
6) In members.php , I set that If cookie is set than show this page else show an error.
7) I always show an error even successfully login. Cookie did not created.

Here is code for jQuery:

```
$.post(url, {php_userName:userName, php_password:password},
            function(data){
                var xyz = (data);

                if (xyz == 'error'){
                    $("#submitMessage").removeClass("JQ_valid").text("");
                    $("#submitMessage").addClass("JQ_Error").text("User name or password is wrong.");
                }else{
                    window.location.replace("members.php?userName="+data);
                }
            })
```

Here is PHP code. (handle_login.php)

```
    if ($DB_UserName == $userName && $DB_password == $md5_pass){
 setcookie($userName, $userType, $expire); 
 echo $userName; 
    }
    else{ 
      echo "error" ;
    }
```

This is member.php code:

```
     $userName = $_REQUEST['userName'] ;
     if(isset($_COOKIE[$userName])){
         //do this
     }else{
          //do this
      }
```

Comment: What are the values of $userType and $expire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for setting cookie is

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
```

So try using,

```
setcookie("cookiename",$userName,0,'/');
```

which will create a cookie with name as given instead of 'cookiename' with value as $userName in the root (/).

And in member.php, use

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename'])){
...
}
```

Comment: I am thankful to you. The basic error was path. My php file, in which there is code for setcookie, is on another path. I just give path '/' as root. and all cookie is set. thanks for your explanation Jenz.